# React Native in Voice Over (iOS) reads out background invisible expo profile tab

Tags: react-native, accessibility, expo, voiceover

Can someone please help me with this issue. 
On Android everything is fine with accessibilityViewIsModal, but on iOS
 Voice Over reads out elements that belong to background invisible Expo's Profile tab.

I tried to set

```
accessibilityViewIsModal={true}
```

to my App's top View, but it didn't work.

Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with Expo App from App Store.

So I rebuilt everything from the ground, upgraded to RN 0.57, deployed with react-native

I mean:

```
$ npm install -g yarn
$ yarn global add react-native-cli
$ react-native init project-name
```

moved my code to the new project and edited package.json with some dependencies

Deployed with

```
$ npm install -g ios-deploy

$ react-native run-ios --device "iPhone - AMI1012"
```

Works just right.